# Create spy for standalone JavaScript function with arguments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

Create spy for standalone JavaScript function with arguments

here function getID is with argument, I created spy and call the getID function and get pass

**I don't know how create spy with argument**

**JS**

```
function school(name, age, rollno)  {
    // do something
}

function getID() {
    //do something
}
```

**Jasmine**

```
var school,
      getID,
      myCtrl;

 beforeEach(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    rootScope = $rootScope;

    getID= jasmine.createSpy('getID');  // this is work fine
    school= jasmine.createSpy('school'); // but this is not working 

    myCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', {

      },
      $scope: scope,
    });

  });

it('getID', function() {            // success
    getID();
     expect(getID).toHaveBeenCalled();

});

it('school', function() {         // gets failed
    school();
     expect(school).toHaveBeenCalled();

});
```

Please help me, to solve this problem

Comment: You don't have to create spy with arguments, in your test call `school(with, argu, ments)`. Spy is for a function, not arguments, if you have to check what it was called with then you can do `school(with, argu, ments).toBeCalledWith(['with', 'argu', 'ments'])`

Comment: Yeah he is right and Jasmin is not related to your question. You are using Jasmine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are testing - that Jasmine has spy functionality?

You've created spy, called it and expecting that spy was called? Something is wrong with logic for those tests.